# Status bar and navigation bar have disappeared

Tags: softkey

I have a Chinese smartphone, Oracle X1 running Android 5.1 that I rooted myself. I wanted to modify the navigation bar using the Softkey Z app. 
Since my last attempt  both the status bar and navigation bar and even the lock screen have disappeared. I tried to install them back with no success.
Please help.

Comment: Salut @Geek, le site n'autorise aucune autre langue que l'anglais car même tu poses ta question en Français, les réponses seront en anglais. Je me suis permis d'apporter la traduction anglaise pour permettre aux autres de comprendre ton problème.

Comment: @esQmo_ **[Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)** Merci :)

Comment: Hey @GokulNC What do I have to understand by that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to flash the stock ROM from the backup you took before messing with it. If you didn't take a backup, you'll need to find a copy of the stock ROM from elsewhere. (See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) ) With a no-name Chinese smartphone, you're quite unlikely to get support from the manufacturer, so you might have to search around XDA forums until you find someone with the same phone.